# OnLeftButtonDown firing with difficulty after putting textblock with canvas.set

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouse, textblock

I have written a C# wpf program that deals with curves on a canvas.
So I load a curve (a sequence of points in a polylinesegment) and then I operate various operations on it. Each curve is put on the screen through mouse interaction and that works fine. Each curve then comes with a textblock in its center which gives out some information.
So the problem comes when I want to mouse-move the shape.
I first select the shape with the mouse (that works) and then I stick it to the cursor through the OnMouseMove event. Eventually I put it down on the with the OnMouseLeftButtonDown event.

So in short the OnMouseLeftButtonDown always works fine except when I have to move the shape AND the label. In that case I have to press several times (randomly) to fire the event.

I have then searched the part which cause the problem and that is when I move the label.

```
    private void UpdateLabel(int index, PathInfo piToBeAdded)
    {
        plotCanvas.Children.Remove(names[index]);

        TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
        text.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        text.FontSize = 12;
        text.Inlines.Add(new Run("(" + (GetPathsIndexFromId(piToBeAdded.ID) + 1) + ")ID:" + piToBeAdded.ID + " " + piToBeAdded.Name) { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
        Canvas.SetLeft(text, piToBeAdded.Center.X);<-----those cause the problem
        Canvas.SetTop(text, piToBeAdded.Center.Y);<------those cause the problem
        text.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        names[index] = text;            
        plotCanvas.Children.Add(text);
    }
```

NB: pathinfo is just a class storing some information among which also coordinates
Specifically it's just the Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop that causes the OnMouseLeftButtonDown not to fire properly. I I take them off the label goes in 0,0 and the event 
But what's wrong with those instructions? How can I make the OnLeftButtonDownEvent to work properly?

I hope that I have described the problem properly I've tried to put all related information.

Thanx in advance

Patrick

Comment: How exactly do you call this method? From OnMouseLeftButtonDown itself?

Comment: That method is called from the OnMouseMove which deals with  moving the shape AND the label following the cursor. That works. It's when I put it down with the OnMouseLeftButtonDown that this event is not firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toadflakz thanx in any case I am not sure if my solution has got to do with what you suggest. In case I will give you the flag.
I noticed that the problem is related with the fact that when moving shape+textblock the mouse point is EXACTLY on the center of the shape (I did that on purpose) and therefore EXACTLY on the textblock. Therefore when I click i don't click on the canvas but on the label. This is why the canvas is not firing. I suppose that the label is firing. So in short I just moved the label some pixels away and that did the trick!!

Comment: You could also set "IsHitTestVisible" of the label to "false". As consequence the label doesn't catch any mousclicks and your code schould work as intended...

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is better to use the `MouseButtonUp` event to release mouse capture as the mouse button has definitely been released at that point and the movement has stopped (which is what you are capturing).

Your issue with `Canvas.SetLeft` is because it can only be called on a child of the `Canvas` object and you are only adding `text` to the `Children` collection after calling `Canvas.SetLeft`.

**Edit:**

In answer to your comment, the `Canvas.SetLeft` can only be called on an existing child of the `Canvas`, so call `Add` before calling `Canvas.SetLeft`.

```
private void UpdateLabel(int index, PathInfo piToBeAdded)
{
    plotCanvas.Children.Remove(names[index]);

    TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
    text.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
    text.FontSize = 12;
    text.Inlines.Add(new Run("(" + (GetPathsIndexFromId(piToBeAdded.ID) + 1) + ")ID:" + piToBeAdded.ID + " " + piToBeAdded.Name) { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
    plotCanvas.Children.Add(text); // <---- moved this up
    Canvas.SetLeft(text, piToBeAdded.Center.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(text, piToBeAdded.Center.Y);
    names[index] = text;
}
```

On the second part of your comment, I would suggest that you attach handlers to the different draggable items and set flags for the appropriate "mode" of operation that you are working in i.e. bool variables for `ShapeDragInProgress` and `LabelDragInProgress`. That way you can then conditionally perform the correct release capture procedure based on the ButtonUp event.

Comment: Ok I will be moving the shape release on the left button up but that's not firing either. As for the problem how can I set the TextBlock position without the Canvas.SetXXX?? I have several shapes on the canvas and that works. When I put the label with that Canvas.Set the problem arises. Any workaround?